# Display posts from #6 to #20 on archive page

Tags: posts, archives, order

My client shows his 5 most recent posts (excerpts) on the homepage followed by a "read more" link. On archive page he does not want to display the 5 most recent post again but posts from #6 to #20.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Add offset in the query and give value as 5 so, the first 5 will be skipped.

Below is code snippet for the same

```
$custom_args = array('post_type' => 'your custom post type name',
'posts_per_page' => '20',
'orderby' => 'id',
'offset'=>5,
'order' => 'ASC',);
$custom_query = get_posts($custom_args);
 foreach ($custom_query as $value) {
 //your data
  }
```

Comment: This means you run a second query after the original archive query. It's better to filter the original query with `pre_get_posts` or similar.

Answer (score 1):

You can filter the original archive query:

```
function my_archive_query( $query ) {
  if ( $query->is_archive() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
    $query->set( 'offset', 5 );
    $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 20 );
  }
}

add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_archive_query' );
```

More info:

[pre_get_posts filter](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts)

[is_archive conditional tag](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_archive)